Why is foreach over pairs of coordinates failing
In How to unpack two points with \foreach this code was suggested:
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x / \y in {(2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}, (2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}, (2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}}
  {
    \draw \x -- \y;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

So far so good, but it's quite fragile. First, Adding a newline after the list closing brace breaks it:
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x / \y in {(2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}, (2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}, (2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}
}
  {
    \draw \x -- \y;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The error is: Package tikz: Cannot parse this coordinate.
Now, using to or edge instead of --:
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x / \y in {(2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}, (2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}, (2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}}
  {
    \draw \x to \y;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

also makes it fail with a maddening list of:

Package pgf: No shape named ``' is known.
Package tikz: (, +, coordinate, pic, or node expected.

messages.
There is no example like this in the user guide. I figure out myself about the need to put non-leading coordinates inside braces, but it's not enough to prevent errors except in the first case. I'm starting to suspect that this usage is not supported.

The newline character will produce a space, causing normal parsing to fail.
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach[count = \cnt] \x / \y in {(2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}, (2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}, (2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)} 
  }
  {
    % \draw \x -- \y;
    \node[scale = .5] at (0, \cnt) {x:-> \meaning\x, y:->\meaning\y};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


You can use comments at the end of the line to avoid this space.
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach[count = \cnt] \x / \y in {(2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}, (2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}, (2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}% 
  }
  {
    % \draw \x -- \y;
    \node[scale = .5] at (0, \cnt) {x:-> \meaning\x, y:->\meaning\y};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


...
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x / \y in {(2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}, (2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}, (2.0,3.0)/{(2.0,5.0)}}
  {
    \expanded{\noexpand\draw \x to \y;}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Yes, I was using comments to work around the issue (although I think it should work with that newline and all, based on typical tikz behavior), but then the curve broke it anyway, so I gave up and just passed 4 scalars separated by 3 slashes. I've opened an issue in github.
